Problem requires an assertion to make sure given string does not have any numbers as part of it. Is there a way to do this without isalnum()?
This is the code I wrote so far. The rubric requires me to assert that the string input has alphabets, whitespaces and some special characters(!,@, etc.), but numbers are to raise an AssertionError. Is there any way to do this without isalnum() or isalpha() as either of them didn't work.
def remove_vowels(message:str)->str:
    """
    Function to identify and remove vowels from a given string
    >>> remove_vowels("TL YAPA")
    'TL YP'
    >>> remove_vowels("remove vowels")
    'rmv vwls'
    >>> remove_vowels("FLY FPX FLY")
    'FLY FPX FLY'
    >>> remove_vowels("expecto patronum")
    'xpct ptrnm'

    """
    assert type(message)==str, "input must be a string"
    count=len(message)
    newstr=""
    for i in range(0,count):
        buffer=message[i]
        if buffer=='a' or buffer=='e' or buffer=='i' or buffer=='o' or buffer=='u':
            continue
        elif buffer=='A' or buffer=='E' or buffer=='I' or buffer=='O' or buffer=='U':
            continue
        else:
            newstr+=buffer
    return newstr


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for tips, like starting with your own research. I just googled python check if string contains numbers and found the linked question.
